# Postgres alter view add column

Tags: postgresql, view

I want to alter a view and add a new column in it. I have:

```
ALTER VIEW folders_contents
AS
SELECT files.id,
    files.name,
    files.filesize,
    files.updated,
    files.deleted,
   FROM files
UNION ALL
 SELECT folders.id,
    folders.name,
    0 AS filesize,
    folders.updated,
    folders.deleted,
    FROM folders
  ORDER BY 8, 2
GO
```

The problem is that it shows:

> [Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"

Is the first time I have to do with views, I need some help :)

Comment: There is no `GO` in Postgres. And `ALTER VIEW` does not what you think it does which is [clearly documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterview.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
ALTER VIEW changes various auxiliary properties of a view. 
(If you want to modify the view's defining query, use CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW.)
```

Use `CREATE OR REPLACE` INSTEAD

In your case, it will be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW folders_contents
AS
SELECT files.id,
    files.name,
    files.filesize,
    files.updated,
    files.deleted,
   FROM files
UNION ALL
 SELECT folders.id,
    folders.name,
    0 AS filesize,
    folders.updated,
    folders.deleted,
    FROM folders
  ORDER BY 8, 2;
```

[SOURCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterview.html)

Comment: the problemnow is that: 
[Err] ERROR:  cannot delete from view "folders_contents"
DETAIL:  Views containing UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT are not automatically updatable.